# Strange behavior when using dynamic parameter in ASPNET WebApi and json request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have really no good explanation what actually is happening and I hope someone here can explain this behavior.

First I go and create File=>NewProject=>Empty WebApi project.

Then I add one simple controller and host this on IIS.

`[RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost, Route("account")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(dynamic command)
        {
            dynamic asd = command;
            return Ok();
        }
    }`

Then I hit the API with fiddler like this:

```
POST https://local.com/api/account HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{"username":"user1","password":"secret","email":"email@domain.com"}
```

Then I put a breakpoint inside the controller and using the Immediate Window

`command.email
'object' does not contain a definition for 'email' and no extension method 'email' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

BUT using the `asd` actually works. How is that? Any idea?

`asd.email
{email@domain.com}
    base: {email@domain.com}
    HasValues: false
    Type: String
    Value: "email@domain.com"`

Even more. If I change the dynamic to ExpandoObject I get the result bellow which I actually expect but through `asd`:

`asd.email
"email@domain.com"`